# How to access clientReferenceId on success using Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm new to Stripe and using what appears to be a very simplistic setup to accept payments using Stripe Checkout. I'm passing a clientReferenceId which I need to access on the success page. Is this possible? Here's the code which is called on the Checkout button:

```
const stripeCheckout = async () => {
    setLoading(true)

    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        lineItems: [
            {
                price: 'price_xxxxx',
                quantity:1,
            }
        ],
        mode:"payment",
        cancelUrl: window.location.origin,
        successUrl: `${window.location.origin}/payment-complete`,
        clientReferenceId: 'abc',
    });

    if (error) {
        console.log("Error @ Checkout: ",error)
        setLoading(false)
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `client_reference_id` by retrieving the Checkout Session on the success page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page

However a much easier solution would be to just encode your variable directly into the success URL:

```js
successURL: `${window.location.origin}/payment-complete?id=abc`,
```

Then on your success page you can just access the query string variables.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you, that's brilliant. So simple! I hadn't thought of that and have been messing around with an express server and cors errors grrr

Comment: Although this approach would let a malicious person pose as if they had completed a successful transaction, which depending on your app may be a bad thing